# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

From this code:

```
if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }else{
```

I have imported `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` [as the docs suggest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users)

My `auth.php` may help

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Do you have an Auth::guard() method defined in your controller? It looks like it is trying to use one of the token guards like the api guard instead of your admin guard.

Answer (score 14):

I think you are probably trying to use a "session" guard driver instead "token". So, try to do this:

In **config/auth.php** configuration file:

```
'admin-api' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'admins',
],
```

You have to change it to

```
'admin-api' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admins',
],
```

Then you should run:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:cache
```

And give it a try again. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't help people who actually are trying to use token guard drivers instead of session guard drivers.

Comment: If your serve command is running in terminal first cancel it then run cache clear commad.

Answer (score 6):

The token guard doesn't have an attempt method, this is a function used in session authentication. So you will need to authorize the users yourself or use the Laravel Passport authentication https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport

Comment: As of mid. last year you could also use Sanctum https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum