# Auth::attempt() trowing an error saying "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()" in Laravel 6.4

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I give a shot to the latest Laravel(6.4). Was trying to implement an API based simple login feature. Didn't use any package like Passport or Tymon's JWT. I used very basic authentication(just keeping a column in the users table naming 'api_token'). But getting en error saying

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

Here is my controller

```
//only method in the controller, so used `__invoke` method.
```

```php
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
         $request->validate([
              'email'    => 'required',
              'password' => 'required',
         ]);

         $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
         $credentials['active'] = 1;

         if (Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
              return response()->json([
                  'data' => 'Wrong credential given'
              ]);
         }

         return response()->json([
             'data' => \auth()->user()
         ]);
    }
```

And this is my `config/auth.php` file status. I am using the api guard for my access. But the token thing should come after login. Here, i am unable to login.

```php
    'defaults' => [
            'guard' => 'api',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],

        'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],

            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'users',
                'hash' => false,
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003253/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-auth-tokenguardattempt)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am providing the right guard and provider. but it's still showing the error i mentioned

Comment: You can use `Auth::once($credentials)`, search for `Authenticate A User Once
` on [this docs page](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication). `. _You may use the once method to log a user into the application for a single request. No sessions or cookies will be utilized, which means this method may be helpful when building a stateless API_

Comment: Now it says "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::once()"

Answer (score 2):

The API Guard does not have an `attempt` method, nor any other form of user login. All it does is protect routes. To authenticate users you should still use the default guard.

Comment: Tried without the auth guard. Same result found

Comment: Do you mean that you tried using Auth::attempt() and still got that error?

Comment: yes, and it's because of the default guard. It should be web

Comment: and yes, you are right,  The API Guard does not have an attempt method

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved when I put the default guard to the `'web'` (as it was earlier). As Alec mention in his answer, `The API Guard does not have an attempt method`. I thought the `api` need to be there for an API call. But it is needed when you want to authorize a user. But before that, you can handle login and registration with the default `web` guard.

So, here is my final changes.
Controller:

```
   $request->validate([
        'email'    => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
    $credentials['active'] = 1;

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => 'Wrong credential given'
    ]);
```

And here is my config/auth.php file

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is changing guard's driver in the config/auth file from token to session like so

```
'guards' => [
    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'my_provider',
        'hash' => false,
    ]
]
```

With that the attempt simply worked like magic. Now I can authenticate users with this middleware like so

```
Auth::guard('staff')->attempt([
    'email' => $r->email, 
    'password' => $r->password
]);
```

access the logged in user's information like this

```
auth('staff')->user();
```

Hope this helps someone.