# I can't get JWT token in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-8

I am creating an API in Laravel 8 (PHP 7.4) and I wanted to secure it. The choice fell on tymon / jwt-auth. I follow the documentation from the website: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/

Everything works fine here. However, later when I create a route to login and want to get the token using *auth()->attempt()*, I have the following error:

> Undefined method 'attempt'.

My Route code:

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    $loginData = request()->only(['email', 'password']);

    $token = auth()->attempt($loginData);

    return $token;
});
```

auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003253/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-auth-tokenguardattempt

Comment: Any idea from this question not working

Comment: Please post your auth.php file

Comment: I have been added it 17 hours ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this line

```
 $token = auth('api')->attempt($loginData);
```